# List.Foreach uses a disposable item in Using block

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I searched and could not find an answer to my question, sorry if this is a duplicate please refer me to correct solution.

I have a entity framework core setup which tracks an object 'TestRun'. I have created a list of TestRuns and wish to add them to the DbContext then write them to the database. This works fine with a regular `ForEach` loop but when I try to use the `List.Foreach` inside the using block Visual Studio suggests that the disposable object is already disposed. "Access to disposed closure".

```
using (var context = new TestResultsContext())
{
    _testRuns.ForEach(t => context.Add(t));
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I figure this has to do with the 'lazy loading' but `ForEach` is a void return so there is no way to force the result to enumerate.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you re: "Access to disposed closure" but there is a `DbContext.AddRange` method that will allow you to add a collection of entities in a single line.  Try that.

Comment: When you say it works with regular foreach do you write it inside `using` as well? Besides `ForEach` is not LINQ. It is regular List<T> class method therefore it is not lazy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<T>.ForEach` is not a LINQ method, that's from the `List<T>` class, and it's also not lazily-evaluated. So regarding the Visual Studio warning, not all warnings should be taken into account, this is one of them. The analyzers are not perfect.

You don't need to use any of those methods, however, since the proper way is use the `DbSet<T>`'s method `AddRange`:

```
using (var context = new TestResultsContext())
{
    context.TestRuns.AddRange(_testRuns);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I also believe that this warning about disposed closure might not be misleading, but to know that for sure more details and broader view on code should be provided.

Comment: @GrayCat It could very well be that the analyzer cannot determine that the method is evaluated instantly or whether context is kept in memory.

Comment: @Camilo Treventinto - you might be right. Still it bugs me what might be the cause